# ASP.NET MVC app routing with NGINX proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an .Net Core (MVC 6) web application running on Linux machine via Kestrel, with NGINX serving as proxy from port 80 -> 5000 
Unfortunately I´m not allowed to use default route as another application has priority, both have to run over port 80, meaning requests are forwarded like:

127.0.0.1 -> another app

127.0.0.1/conf -> my app

And in NGINX config file it's defined as:

```
     location /conf {
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;            
        proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;            
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;            
        proxy_send_timeout      90;            
        proxy_read_timeout      90;            
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;
  }
```

The thing is, if I run application using standard location ( location / ) , routing of MVC app runs fine. But having /conf appended to proxy simply breaks MVC routing, because application continues to return routes that are based on root location, without /conf prefix. So after user gets to default landing page, all routes (links, actions) are still pointing to address like 127.0.0.1/Home/About instead of 127.0.0.1/conf/Home/About - and to make it even worse, these links (/conf/Home/About) are not working either.

Any suggestions on how should I proceed in solving this ? Should some route prefix be specified in MVC app on general level (currently it uses only default route) or there is some NGINX-based solution (that would be more preferrable) ?
I tried googling half a day and wasn't able to find similar situation, so I really appreciate any input on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same issue.

I am not sure it is the best thing to do but I changed the path to make it relative. Here is what it looks like :

```html
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

became

<link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and same for images and scripts.

Also I had to change form and links which means :

```html
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">

became

<form action="./" method="get">
```

And

```html
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-SearchInput="@Model.SearchInput">

became

<a href="./?SearchInput=@(Model.SearchInput)">
```

I kind of loose the power of asp tags but that is the only I found to make it work in these conditions.

I hope this can help